# sliding door Button element broke in Firefox only

Tags: css, firefox, button, sliding-doors

I'm trying to do a sliding door button that can be used in general purpose 
everything works fine  except the Firefox.
the span element in button always lower 2px in FF.

here is example

http://jsbin.com/orami3/4

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
button::-moz-focus-inner { 
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

(Mind that the colon (**:**) is doubled, yes.)

The extra padding in this case is caused by an obscure Firefox bug.

(Having encountered this bug myself I've found the solution [at this blog](http://www.aheadcreative.com/removing-unwanted-button-padding-in-firefox/), via a Google search.)

Comment: This also removes the focus ring, which may eventually cause you to have accessibility issues, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know why this happens, but there is some strangeness here.  It affects Safari as well, and it's slightly different.  If you add a negative margin to the button span, it will move half the distance in Firefox than it does in Safari.  So, the solution seems to offset the background-image.  Here is one way to hack it:

```
/*grey button hacks non-IE*/
button.grey span{
  background-position: 0 -1px;
}
button.grey:hover span{
  background-position: 0 -36px;      
}
button.grey:active span{
   background-position: 0 -71px;      
}

/* IE workaround.  The \9 makes non-IE ignore these styles*/
button.grey span{
  background-position: 0 0px\9;
}
button.grey:hover span{
  background-position: 0 -35px\9;      
}
button.grey:active span{
   background-position: 0 -70px\9;      
}
```

Example here: http://jsbin.com/orami3/9